# Requesting and Responding data in JSON format using Azure Functions

Tags: python, json, azure-functions

I am trying to load time series data from a JSON file to Azure Functions using `req.get_json()` in Python and I would like the function to return a JSON file after some simple mathematical operations.
My JSON file looks like:

```
{ "Timestamp":{"0": "1500069600000","1": "1500073200000"}, "Data":{"0":"3","1":"4"}}
```

And I want to get a result in a JSON format which should be as follows (which is simply increasing the Data values by 1):

```
{ "Timestamp":{"0": "1500069600000","1": "1500073200000"}, "Data":{"0":"4","1":"5"}}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this, since this is my first time to work with Azure Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return JSON body in Azure function, please refer to the following code

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    data =req.get_json()
    
    for key in data["Data"].keys():
          data["Data"][key]=4     
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),
        mimetype="application/json",)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked pretty well. But I have a problem when importing pandas library in Azure Functions and it keeps telling me that the module named 'pandas' does not exist. So I would appreciate it if you could help me figure out a way for that.

Comment: @NJE To better help you, I suggest you raise a new issue to describe your issue in detail. Besides, since the issue has been solved, could you please accept it as an answer? it may help more people who have the similar issue.